# In Vue 3, primitive types like string, what's the difference if we use PropType or not in props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

The [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props) says

> Vue does a runtime validation on props with a type defined. To provide
> these types to TypeScript, we need to cast the constructor with
> PropType

The sample in that document uses `success: { type: String }` instead of `success: { type: String as PropType<string>}`. So for `string` is there any differences of these two? for example

```
props: {
  title: {
    type: String as PropType<string>,
    default: () => '',
  },
  subTitle: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
},
```

Comment: You would use `PropType` to define a stricter type if you wished, say a union of some strings.

Comment: I don't think this will produce different outputs, both are the same things. But it could be possible the IDE will better able to understand the props title type.

Answer (score 2):

In runtime, there will be no difference between the two types (there will be an extra function call to get the default value for the title property though). The `PropType` is not needed in this case.

In Vue, the `type` key for property definitions serves as a hint for Vue's validation when values are being assigned to the component, it expects a constructor that Vue can compare the passed instance to in **runtime** and will emit a warning if not. This part works the same whether you write your code in typescript or plain javascript (of course, in design time, typescript will still complain if you try to add a number to a property with type String).

For typescript to have to correct types for component properties, the generic javascript constructors are not enough, so extra information is added in the form of `PropType<>`. Vue uses this to infer the exact type of the property and have the correct typing for component instances. This only happens in design/build time and is discarded when the code is compiled to javascript.

The `PropType<>` is still useful for String, for example, if you need to narrow the type to certain typescript values:

```
type Color = "red" | "blue";


props: {
    color: {
        type: String as PropType<Color>
    }
}
```

So in runtime, Vue can validate that only strings are assigned to color property but in design time, typescript can ensure that you don't try to assign anything but "blue" or "red" strings to it.